# Nested struct breaks constexpr despite being identical to global ones

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

I'm having trouble with the following code:

```
template<typename T>
constexpr int get(T vec) {
  return vec.get();
}

struct coord {
  constexpr int get() const { return x; }
  int x;
};

struct foo {
    struct coord2 {
      constexpr int get() const { return x; }
      int x;
    };
    constexpr static coord f = { 5 };
    constexpr static int g = get(f); // works

    constexpr static coord2 h = { 5 };
    constexpr static int i = get(h); // doesn't work
};

constexpr coord foo::f;
constexpr foo::coord2 foo::h;

int main(){}
```

Essentially, `get(f)` is considered a constant expression, but `get(h)` is not. The only thing changed is that one uses a global struct `coord`, while the other uses a nested struct `coord2`. The structs'
 bodies are identical.

Why is this?

---

GCC error:

```
test.cpp:20:35: error: field initializer is not constant
```

Clang error:

```
test.cpp:20:26: error: constexpr variable 'i' must be initialized by a constant expression
    constexpr static int i = get(h); // doesn't work
                         ^   ~~~~~~
test.cpp:8:10: note: undefined function 'get' cannot be used in a constant expression
  return vec.get();
         ^
test.cpp:20:30: note: in call to 'get({5})'
    constexpr static int i = get(h); // doesn't work
                             ^
test.cpp:13:21: note: declared here
      constexpr int get() const { return x; }
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is a constant expression.... eventually, as this shows you can see by moving `i` into `main()`:

- http://ideone.com/lucfUi

The error messages are pretty clear what's going on, which is that `foo::coord2::get()` isn't defined yet, because member function definitions are delayed until the end of the enclosing class so that they can use members declared later.

It's a little surprising that the definition is delayed until the end of the outermost enclosing class, but you'd be even more surprised if `foo::coord2::get()` couldn't access `foo::g`.

The Standard agrees with the compiler, btw.  Part of section 9.2p2 says

> Within the class *member-specification*, the class is regarded as complete **within function bodies**, default arguments, *exception-specifications*, and *brace-or-equal-initializers* for non-static data members **(including such things in nested classes)**.

Unfortunately, it's only inferred that the closing brace of the class declaration becomes the point-of-definition for these deferred regions.  I believe it's a defect in the Standard that it doesn't say this explicitly.

See also:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/11523155/103167

Comment: @dyp: Isn't that what I said? (It is inferred, it is not explicit)

Comment: Ah, OK, I misunderstood that paragraph, sorry.

Comment: @Somnium: Move your initializers out-of-line?  IIRC, you can use a `constexpr` initializer for a `const static` data member.