# Strange constexpr behaviour for inner class

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

Can anybody try to explain this?

```
template<typename T, size_t S = T::noElems()>
struct C
{
};

struct X
{
    enum E { A, B, C };
    static constexpr size_t noElems() { return C+1; };
};

struct K
{
    C<X> cx; // this DOES compile
};

struct Y
{
    struct Z
    {
        enum E { A, B, C };
        static constexpr size_t noElems() { return C+1; };
    };
    C<Z, Z::C+1> cyz; // this DOES compile

    C<Z> cyz; // <--- this does NOT compile 
};
```

Comment: Clang complains `undefined function 'noElems' cannot be used in a constant expression`

Comment: I think it might be answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8108406/4035785)

Comment: Can you add the compilation error into your question?

Comment: @Angew http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a60f331bbefa3bab

Comment: @RafalMielniczuk : why only with inner classes? Why does `C<X> cx;` compile then?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16554867/nested-struct-breaks-constexpr-despite-being-identical-to-global-ones

Comment: @gd1 struct X is declared outside of struct Y so it was parsed before

Comment: @T.C. : very interesting, I'll have a look.

Comment: I suspect @RafalMielniczuk is correct, as `C<Z, Z::noElems()>` will exhibit the same problem.

Comment: This can be illustrated with even simpler code http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6cba58b8bf0b9f50

Comment: See [CWG issue 1626](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1626).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the declaration of the struct

```
struct Y
{
    struct Z
    {
        enum E { A, B, C };
        static constexpr size_t noElems() { return C+1; };
    };
    C<Z, Z::C+1> cyz1; // this DOES compile

    C<Z> cyz2; // <--- this does NOT compile 
};
```

entities `cyz1` and `cyz2` are parsed before inline declaration of `Z::noElems()`, so the definition of

```
static constexpr size_t noElems() { return C+1; };
```

is not available at the time of declaration of

```
C<Z> cyz2;
```

Comment: +1 Nice answer. Wondering how Z::C is available, then.

Comment: I editet my answer, I think it is about noElems being inline, which makes the compiler to parse it after the cyz's declarations, while enum E is available, that's why cyz1 works