# compile-time evaluation of a function to compute a constant

Tags: c++, constants, constexpr

Preamble: I've looked at [constexpr initializing static member using static function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11522399/constexpr-initializing-static-member-using-static-function), but (thanks to Oleg Bogdanov's answer) I'm not trying to initialize a static.

I'd like to know how to make the following work:

```
typedef uint32_t color_t;       // represent color as 00rrggbb

class Color {
  static color_t makeColor(const uint8_t r,
                           const uint8_t g,
                           const uint8_t b) {
    return (((color_t)r << 16) | ((color_t)g << 8) | (color_t)b);
  }  
  static const color_t kRed = makeColor(255, 0, 0);
}
```

As I see it, the compiler needs to be told that it can evaluate `makeColor()` at compile time, so I think this is a job for `constexpr`.  Despite my best efforts at sprinkling around `constexpr` and `const`, I still get

```
error: field initializer is not constant
```

What am I missing?

P.S.: I can certainly accomplish what I want with #define:

```
#define makeColor(r, g, b) (((color_t)(r) << 16) | ((color_t)(g) << 8) | (color_t)(b))
```

... but that seems so 20th century!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you were very close to your goal, making `makeColor` constexpr would be enough if you remove `static` from `kRed`

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/g/RVhjNi)

Why exactly `static` is problematic is explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11522399/constexpr-initializing-static-member-using-static-function)

Comment: Perfect - thanks.  (And thanks also for the pointer to https://godbolt.org)

Comment: Happy to help. Matt Godbolt's project is probably the best thing that happened to c++ community in recent years :)